# How to set state in react from IIFE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, state, iife

I am new to **Immediately Invoked Function Expressions**. I am creating a React JS web app and learned about **IIFEs** to be able to define an accumulator variable for use within a mapping function. My goal with this is to sum table columns in a `debit` column and a `credit` column, then allow a user to submit the table information only if the two columns "balance" or are the same amounts. Here is my **IIFE** within my react component:

```
{
    (() => {
        let debit = 0;
        let credit = 0;

        return rows.map((item) => {
            debit += this.state.accountDebits;
            credit += this.state.accountCredits;
            
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder={item}></input></td>
                    <td><Options accountArray={this.props.accountArray} numberLine={item} testing={this.setAccounts} resetFields={this.state.resetFields}></Options></td>
                    <td><DescriptionField numberLine={item} getDescription={this.setDescription} resetFields={this.state.resetFields}></DescriptionField></td>
                    <td><DebitField numberLine={item} getDebit={this.setDebit} resetFields={this.state.resetFields}></DebitField></td>
                    <td><CreditField numberLine={item} getCredit={this.setCredit} resetFields={this.state.resetFields}></CreditField></td>
                    <td><ApplicableConnectionField numberLine={item} getConnection={this.setConnection} resetFields={this.state.resetFields}></ApplicableConnectionField></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    })()
}
```

However, here is my problem. I want the user to go about filling out the table. I am accumulating the sum of the `debit` and `credit` column during this process. However, I need to access these variables outside the scope of this function in order to compare them when the user clicks the submit button (which I render later in the component). I want to set the `debit` and `credit` variables to state, but the **IIFE** syntax is giving me some trouble. How can I set these variables to state?

Comment: _"IIFE within my react component"_ may you share the rest of this component?

Comment: Looks like IIFE is rendering. We should not set state in render function.

Comment: I don't think you should be using an IIFE here at all. Where does it even `return` to in your current code? That looks like a useless block to me.

Comment: "*I need to access these variables outside the scope of this function*" - just declare them in the upper scope where you need them, not locally in that IIFE?